# How to dynamically change a CSS seconds value

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

```js
var timerSeconds = 10;  // This will be set from a DB value

function StartCountDownTimer() {
  var timerStart = new Date();
  var css_seconds = `${timerSeconds}s`;
  
  css_root = document.querySelector(':root');
  
  cssVarBefore = '--timer-seconds BEFORE being set by JS: ' + getComputedStyle(css_root).getPropertyValue('--timer-seconds');
  
  css_root.style.setProperty('--timer-seconds', css_seconds);
  
  cssVarAfter = '--timer-seconds AFTER being set by JS: ' + getComputedStyle(css_root).getPropertyValue('--timer-seconds');
  
  document.querySelector('.progress-border').classList.add('progress-border-animation');

  timerStart.setSeconds(timerStart.getSeconds() + timerSeconds);
  timerStart = timerStart.getTime();

  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = timerStart - now;
    var seconds = Math.round(distance / 1000, 1000);
    document.getElementById("seconds-remaining").innerHTML = seconds;

    if (seconds < 1) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("seconds-remaining").innerHTML = "";
      document.querySelector('.progress-border').classList.remove('progress-border-animation');
      alert("This demonstrates that the CSS variable is actually being changed it just isn't affecting the animation duration\n\n" + cssVarBefore + '\n' + cssVarAfter);      
     }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;

/* this is the variable I'm trying to set from JavaScript */
  --timer-seconds: 5s;
  --box-size: 150px;
  --border-width: 8px;
}

body {
  margin: 3em;  
}

container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: columns;
  gap: 1em;
}

.secs {
  color: #365a2a;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.count-down-timer{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: var(--box-size);
  height: var(--box-size);
  border: var(--border-width) solid #c05b20;
  border-radius: calc(var(--border-width)*2);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: linear-gradient(#599646, #bfe2c3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progress-border {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--border-width)*-1);
  left: calc(var(--border-width)*-1);
  width: var(--box-size);
  height: var(--box-size);
  border-radius: calc(var(--border-width)*2);
}

.progress-border-animation {
  border: var(--border-width) solid #365a2a;
  animation: fill forwards linear;
  animation-duration: var(--timer-seconds);  /* this line doesn't work */
  /* animation-duration: 10s; */ /* this line works */
}

@keyframes fill {
  0% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 0%);
  }
  12.5% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%);
  }
  25% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 120.71% 50%, 120.71% 50%, 120.71% 50%, 120.71% 50%, 100% 0%);
  }
  37.5% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  50% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 50% 120.71%, 50% 120.71%, 50% 120.71%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  62.5% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  75% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, -20.71% 50%, -20.71% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  87.5% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  }
  100% {
clip-path: polygon(50% -20.71%, 50% 50%, 50% -20.71%, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <container>
      <div>
        <p><b>Click on the box to start the timer</b></p><br>
        <div onclick="StartCountDownTimer()" class="count-down-timer">
          <p class="secs" id="seconds-remaining"></p>
          <div class="progress-border"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p><b>This is where I need help:</b></p>
        <p>The CSS variable used for animation duration of the border is being set to 10 seconds to match the count down timer but the border is still using the original value of 5 seconds for its animation.  <b>WHY?</b>
        </p>
      </div>
    </container>
  </body>
</html>
```

Trying to figure out how to dynamically change the seconds value for a CSS animation duration.  I statically set the value in the class to 20s.  From JavaScript I want to be able to change the 20s to some dynamic value, e.g. 60s.  I'm using the value in JS to do other iterations so I need it to be an integer in JS.  I think the issue I'm having is using different data types integer vs seconds but I'm not sure.

I've tried a few different approaches but none have worked:

1. changing CSS integer variable --sec: 20, from JS, then using calc(0s + var(--sec)) for the animation duration.
2. changing CSS seconds variable --sec: 20s, from JS by concatenating (60 + 's') and using var(--sec) for the animation duration.
3. modifying the document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0].style.animationDuration value from JS by concatenating (60 + 's')

Any suggestions would be much appreciated...

Comment: Please post snippets of the actual CSS and actual code. What is not happening, the duration is not changing, or the duration is disappearing, or the next time animation is expected it is not happenig at all?

Comment: I posted a snippet of code that demonstrates the issue I'm experiencing.  Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE regarding the latest posted code**

It seems that the CSS variables are not defined in `:root {}`, instead are in `* {}`, therefore the `setProperty()` did not work.

If you move them to `:root {}` it should work properly:

```
:root {
  --timer-seconds: 5s;
  --box-size: 150px;
  --border-width: 8px;
}
```

**Update regarding custom duration input**

You can also set `ms` as value of `animation-duration` in CSS.

[More about `animation-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration)

Here is an over simplified example, it sets a value in `ms` to `animation-duration` by changing a variable `--duration` on the animated element.

There are many other ways, but this seems to be straight forward.

Hope this will help.

```js
const figure = document.querySelector("figure");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button:not(#custom)");
const btnCustom = document.querySelector("button#custom");
const input = document.querySelector("input");

btnCustom.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  const {value} = input
  if (!value || isNaN(value) || value < 100 || value > 2000) {
    input.value = ""
    return}
  const duration = `${Math.floor(value)}ms`
  figure.style.setProperty("--duration", duration)
})

btns.forEach((btn) =>
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) =>
    figure.style.setProperty("--duration", e.target.dataset.duration)
  )
)
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 6px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 6px;
}

.control {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 3px;
}

button {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 3px;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 3px;
}

.animation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #fdf5e6;
}

figure {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1e90ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: move alternate infinite linear;
  animation-duration: var(--duration, 1200ms);
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="control">
    <input
      type="number"
      min="100"
      max="2000"
      step="100"
      placeholder="Enter num between 100 and 2000"
    />
    <button id="custom">Set custom duration in ms</button>
  </div>

  <div class="control">
    <button data-duration="1200ms">Defalut</button>
    <button data-duration="700ms">Fast</button>
    <button data-duration="300ms">Faster</button>
  </div>
  <div class="animation">
    <figure></figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response John.  What I'm trying to do is take your example and have an input field where you enter a number of seconds.  Then add that number to the current animation duration.  Your example has three static options to choose from.  The problem I'm running into is adding an integer to a value with a sec or ms suffix.  I've tried --- animation-duration: calc(val(--input-ms)+ "ms") --- but that doesn't seem to work for me?

Comment: @Michael I just updated the example with custom duration input. I think you might be over complicating it with `calc()` because `--duration` can be just a string. Hope the example will help at least as a reference. Thanks!

Comment: I modified my code snippet above to better demonstrate the issue I'm still having.  I'm assuming it's probably something simple since it's been about 15 years since I left the coding arena and I'm just hunting and pecking to resolve most of the issues I'm having.  Just haven't been able to figure this one out yet.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Michael It seems that your CSS variables are not defined in `:root {}`, instead are in `* {}`. If you move them to `:root {}` it seems to work properly. The answer is too long to add but here is a live: [codepen](https://codepen.io/john-zhuangzhuang-li/pen/VwdQrPq). Hope it will help!

Comment: Well that was easy.  Thanks I really appreciate your help and support.  Happy Thanksgiving !!!

Comment: @Michael Glad to hear it works! Thanks and same to you.